# How to properly document the Props parameter of a React component when using Destructuring assignment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsdoc

I am trying to write the JSDocs for a React component that uses destructuring assignment to get the props as follows.

```js
const PostComponent: React.FC<IPostComponent> = ({ title, body }) => { ... }
```

The problem I have is that JSDocs expects to have one `@param` since PostComponent only accepts one component, but I'd like to document `title` and `body` as parameters of the component.

If I try to include them as parameters VScode shows a warning as expected:

```js
/**
 * @component
 * @param {string} title the title of the post
 * @param {string} body the body of the post
 */
const PostComponent: React.FC<IPostComponent> = ({ title, body }) => { ... }
```

If I document each parameter in the `IPostComponent` interface, the documentation is shown when hovering over the fields, but it is not included in the component documentation

```js
interface eIPostComponent {
  /** The title of the post */
  title: string;
  /** The body of the post */
  body: string;
}
```

What is the preferred way to include JSDocs for this component?

Answer (score 0):

Your function accepts only one parameter - an object.
You can document it while referencing it in the doc:

```
/**
 * @component
 * @param {obj} wrapping object
 * @param {string} obj.title title the title of the post
 * @param {string} obj.body the body of the post
 */
const PostComponent: React.FC<IPostComponent> = ({ title, body }) => { ... }
```